# Array to string conversion Laravel upload multiples images

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to save multiple images of my property, a property can have several images, but I get this error

I would like to know what it produces if you can help me here I leave my controller in the store function

code upload image

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {
      /*--from this session you start to save the properties with all their attributes  --*/
      
        $properti = new Propertie;

        $detail = new Detail;

        $detail->antiquity = $request->antiquity;
        $detail->furnished = $request->furnished;
        $detail->floor = $request->floor;

        $detail->save();

        $properti->details_id = $detail->id;

        $properti->name = $request->name;
        $properti->price = $request->price;
        $properti->description = $request->description;


        $properti->departaments_id = $request->departaments;
        $properti->municipalities_id = $request->municipalities;

        $properti->property_type_id = $request->type_property;
        $properti->offer_type_id = $request->type;


        $properti->details_id = $detail->id;
        $properti->images = $request->images;
        $properti->lat = $request->lat;
        $properti->lng = $request->lng;
        $properti->address = $request->address;


        if (isset($request->property_id)) {
            $property_type = $request->property_id;
        } else {
            $property_type = null;
        }
        
         $images=array();
        if($files=$request->file('images')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image',$name);
            $images[]=$name;
            }
        }

        $properti->save();


        $piso_id = $properti->id;
        $space = new Space;

        $space->property_id = $piso_id;
        $space->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms;
        $space->bathrooms = $request->bathrooms;
        $space->parking = $request->parking;
        $space->area = $request->area;


        $space->save();

        $properti->spaces_id = $space->id;


        foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {

            $charc = new Characteristic;

            $charc->property_id = $piso_id;
            $charc->characteristic = $characteristic;
            $charc->save();
        }    

        Session::flash('message', 'Se ha registrado su propiedad De forma exitosa');

        return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
        // return view('properties.index',compact('properties'));
    }
```

Migration - Properties

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable;
            $table->string('price')->nullable;
            $table->text('description')->nullable;
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('offer_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('spaces_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('departaments_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('municipalities_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('details_id')->nullable();
            //$table->unsignedBigInteger('characteristics_id')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('images_id')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('lat', 8, 5)->nullable;
            $table->decimal('lng', 8, 5)->nullable;
            $table->string('address')->nullable;
            
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('property_type_id')->references('id')->on('property_type');
            $table->foreign('offer_type_id')->references('id')->on('offer_type');
            $table->foreign('spaces_id')->references('id')->on('spaces');
            $table->foreign('departaments_id')->references('id')->on('departaments');
            $table->foreign('municipalities_id')->references('id')->on('municipalities');
            $table->foreign('details_id')->references('id')->on('details');
            $table->foreign('images_id')->references('id')->on('images');
           //$table->foreign('characteristics_id')->references('id')->on('characteristics')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

Migration images

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my property model

```
  public function Images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'images_id');
    }
```

model images

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'property_id'];
    
   public function properties()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Properties');
    }
}
```

I don't know if I have something wrong with my controller but it gives me the error before saving it

Comment: well if you look at your error message and stack trace it tells you what line causes the error, so then you can focus on fixing it. Would you like to provide the error the line is on or part of the stack trace?

Comment: What line specifically is throwing that error? This is a pretty large code-dump, so it would be helpful if you point us in the right direction. Sidenote, you're defining the `$images` array, and pushing `$name` values to it, but never using it beyond that.

Comment: the error throws it to me in the line of $ property-> save ();

If I do a dd before it, it throws the array at me with the images

Comment: I scrolling and scrolling and at least I reached here...

Comment: May be error here `$properti->images = $request->images;` its not a field, its a relationship with `Image` model

Comment: yes how would I solve there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assigning an array to `images`:

```
$properti->images = $request->images;
```

You are then calling `$properti->save()` which is trying to save that array, which it can't; it will try to convert it to a string, which it can't. So you can comment/remove this line.

If you want to save these via the relationship you can try something like this:

```
$properti->save();

foreach($files as $file) {
    $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('image',$name);
    
    // create a new Image and relate it to the property
    $properti->images()->create(['name' => $name]);
}
```

Comment: idk, how can you save an array of data to a single field? is that even what you actually want to do?

Comment: <input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" placeholder="Imagenes" multiple>

So I have my input for the images

Comment: @cesar you make a foreach to get all image as single, you can insert then all in your Image model

Comment: you will have to save these images to the images table and link them to the property, which you can do with the same loop you are currently using for the images

Comment: If I want the images table to save all the images with the property id, and so every time I create a property

Comment: Also, you have a field named `property_id`, you cant get the id before `$property->save ()` So you need to save those image name after `$property->save ()`

Comment: I get the error

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: files
```